# Cron is stuck / fails to run in Drupal 7.22

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cron

Drupal says that cron failed to run - and it seems as if it was stuck. I've tried to delete the MySQL-entries that indicate the cron-session. 
The problem appears only on one single machine. If I install the same drupal environment somewhere else, it's working. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the watchdog logs for this error?

Comment: So it's possible that you're missing something on the machine required to finish the cron job. As @TheodorosPloumis asked, what are the watchdog errors? Go into your site reports to find it.

Comment: @Tomaslukas any progress with this?

Comment: unfortunately not. reinstalled the system over and over again. that helped :-(